# one in a matrix full of zeros - R

Tags: r

I am new to programming and I am trying to figure it how can I make a matrix with all zeros and insert just a random one? 
I've looked for help but I can only find code to create a random matrix with zeros and ones but I only want a "one" to appear at random places in a matrix.

I've looked in here for example, 
http://www.r-bloggers.com/making-matrices-with-zeros-and-ones/

```
set.seed(1)
mm <- matrix(0, 10, 5)
apply(mm, c(1, 2), function(x) sample(c(0, 1), 1))

#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]    0    0    1    0    1
#  [2,]    0    0    0    1    1
#  [3,]    1    1    1    0    1
#  [4,]    1    0    0    0    1
#  [5,]    0    1    0    1    1
#  [6,]    1    0    0    1    1
#  [7,]    1    1    0    1    0
#  [8,]    1    1    0    0    0
#  [9,]    1    0    1    1    1
# [10,]    0    1    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 12):

Creating all-zeros matrix is easy

```
X <- matrix(0, 10, 10)
```

now notice that matrix in R is stored as a vector with additional dimension

```
> str(X)
 num [1:10, 1:10] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

so if you want to insert `1` on a random position, than just pick a random position in vector of length N*M and replace it with the value

```
X[sample(10*10, 1)] <- 1
```